# The Rössler attractor

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

```
s = NDSolve[{
    Derivative[1][x][t] == -y[t] - z[t],
    Derivative[1][y][t] == x[t] + 0.1 y[t],
    Derivative[1][z][t] == .01 + z[t] (x[t] - 14),
    x[0] == z[0] == 0, y[0] == 0}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 400},
    MaxSteps -> Infinity];
Show[ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 400},
     PlotPoints -> 2000, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, RGBColor[0, 0, 0]],
     ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors", #1] &)],
     Graphics3D[{ColorData["SolarColors"][0],
                 Sphere[First[({x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. s) /. t -> 0], 1]}],
     RotationAction -> "Clip", Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> False, 
     Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 500]
```

When I do this code it only shows a picture of part of the [Rossler attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6ssler_attractor), even though the derivatives are correct.  What's going wrong?

Comment: Add the `PlotRange -> All` option to `Graphics3D`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi still not working for me

Comment: That is odd. What version of Mathematica are you running? I am on `11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)`. When I add that option I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z4Zn.jpg).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi It is the latest version. Can you send me the complete code you entered?  I may be doing something wrong (I'm new to this).

Comment: I copied exactly what you posted and added `PlotRange -> All` as the last argument to `Plot`. Perhaps you have some previously bound symbol that is interfering. Try evaluating `ClearAll["Global`*"]` first.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Oh, it works now.  I put it in the wrong place earlier.  Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `PlotRange -> All`

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 400}, 
  PlotPoints -> 2000, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, RGBColor[0, 0, 0]], 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors", #1] &)], 
 Graphics3D[{ColorData["SolarColors"][0], 
   Sphere[First[({x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. s) /. t -> 0], 1]}], 
 RotationAction -> "Clip", Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> False, 
 Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]